# Is this function defined over a rational rectangle integrable?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Let $Q_0 = \{ x : x\in \mathbb{Q} , 0\leq x \leq 1 \}$ and let $f:R_Q \to \mathbb{R}$ with $R_Q = Q_0 \times Q_0$. f defined as:

$$ 
f(x,y)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lc}
             \sin(x) &   \text{if}  \; 0\leq y \leq x^2 \\
             \\ \hspace{0.5cm} 0 &  \text{in other case} \\
             \end{array}
   \right.
$$

Is this function integrable over $R_Q$?

My attempt:

For $0\leq y \leq x^2 $:

$$ f(x,y) = g(x) \ h(y) \ \text{ with } \ g:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R} , \ \ g(x)=\sin(x), \ h:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R} \ \ h(y) = 1 $$

Restriction of continuous functions is continuous then $g$ and $h$ are continuous functions, consequently $f$ is continuous because is a product of continuous functions. Therefore $f$ is integrable over $R_Q$.

Is the above correct? If so, how is the integral computed?

Comment: Looks correct to me let anyone else confirm

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is not quite complete. You've shown that the function $\ f\ $ is continuous, and hence integrable, over the set $\ A=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}^2\right.\,\left|\,0\le x\le 1, 0\le y\le x^2\right\}\ $.  However, $\ f\ $ is *not* continuous over $\ R_Q\ $, so this is not sufficient to establish its integrability over that set. It is not continuous at the point $\ \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}\right)\in R_Q\ $, for instance, because $\ f\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}\right)\ne0\ $, but $\ \lim_\limits{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}f\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}+\epsilon\right)=0\ $.

The easiest way to establish the integrability of $\ f\ $ over $\ R_Q\ $ is to note that $\ R_Q\ $ is countable, and therefore has measure $\ 0\ $.  *All* real-valued functions are integrable over any set of measure $\ 0\ $, and their integrals over such a set are always $\ 0\ $.

Comment: It is clear that $(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi^2}{16}) \notin R_Q , \frac{\pi}{4} \notin \mathbb{Q}, \frac{\pi^2}{16} \notin \mathbb{Q} $

Comment: Oops. I simply didn't notice the $\ \mathbb{Q}\ $ in the definition of $\ Q_0\ $.